# Align content vertically with flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I am creating a tile where the image can either be 50% of the tile or 75% of the tile and content will fill the remaining area/ space left. My issue is I don't want to set a specific height for the image as it will lose it's image/aspect ratio. I have something like the following below:

```
const tile= () => (
  <StyledWrapper>
    <StyledImageBlock>
      //get Image here
    </StyledImageBlock>
      <StyledTextContent>
        {getTitleOne()} //this is a span element
        {getTitleTwo()} //this is a span element
      </StyledTextContent>}
  </StyledWrapper>
);
```

In my `StyledWrapper` I have the following:

```
  text-align: center;

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

In my `StyledImageBlock` I have the following:

```
  width: 100%;
```

In my `StyledTextContent` I have the following:

```
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

But items refuse to be vertically aligned, I set a height on the `StyledWrapper` to `height: 700px` just for demo and still refuses. Where am I going wrong here? Any suggestions on how to achieve what I have described.

Some more information. I can achieve the desired result when setting a percentage height on the image and content but with this the image aspect ration changes to be worse/ stretches the image which I do not want. Ultimately this tile will be going into a flexbox grid.

Comment: It would be great if you posted the resulting HTML and CSS in a form of a [mcve] reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put

```
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

on *StyledWrapper*. This will center the *StyledImageBlock* vertically and horizontally.

Comment: That works but also aligns the image, I need the image to stay at the top of the tile and any content below to be centered, the trouble i'm having is the content and image have to specified height, I want it to take 100% of available height in the grid (which is currently does), just cant center text in remaining space without setting  a height

Answer (score 0):

in the `<StyledWrapper>` set.

`justify-content: center;` to center in x-axis, and,

`align-items: center;` to center in the.

The parent element when you define `display: flex` is a box, where you can set how the childs will interact.

[flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) ( Set width of the first element, affect the element where is defined )

[flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) ( Set direction of how element will be display , to be use in parent class of childs fleboxes )

[flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)  ( How width it's gonna take an element in the x-axis, affect the element where is defined)

[flex-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) ( How it's display the childs in the x-axis, to be use in parent class of childs fleboxes )

[flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) ( How width it's gonna take to shrink, affect the element where is defined)

[flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) ( forced onto one line or can wrap onto multiple lines, to be use in parent class of childs fleboxes )